# Qt5 overload slots error

Tags: qt

For example

```
class A : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    void f(int);
    void f();
};

A a;
QAction action(0);

connect(&action, &QAction::triggered, &a, &A::f); // error because 2 f functions.
```

How to overcome it besides renaming one of the 2 overloaded functions? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QT5 still supports the "old" way of connecting using complete prototypes:

```
connect((&action, SIGNAL(triggered()), &a, SLOT(f(int));
```

or

```
connect((&action, SIGNAL(triggered()), &a, SLOT(f());
```

EDIT: using the new way can be done with a cast (have not tried it myself):

```
connect((&action, &QAction::triggered, &a, static_cast<void (A::*)(int)>(&A::f));
```

Comment: How about if keep using the new feature? Does the first statement works? Seem it requires the argument match between signals and slots.